# a little confused about "return"

Tags: ruby

Below is the code that I saw in a book, which prints `"23"`:

```
M = 'land'
o = 'water'
world = [[o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o],
     [o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o,o],
     [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o],
     [o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o,M,o],
     [o,o,o,M,o,M,M,o,o,o,o],
     [o,o,o,o,M,M,M,M,o,o,o],
     [o,o,o,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,o],
     [o,o,o,M,M,o,M,M,M,o,o],
     [o,o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o],
     [o,M,o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o],
     [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o]]

def continent_size world,x,y
  if world[y][x] != 'land'
    size =0
  else
    size = 1
  end

  world[y][x] = 'counted land'

  size = size + continent_size(world,x-1,y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x , y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y )
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y )
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y+1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x , y+1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y+1)
  size

end
puts continent_size(world, 5, 5)
```

I am curious why this code does not work if I remove `return` before `size=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the recursion, which must be stopped immediately after the *“non-land”* field is found.

`return` terminates the function execution and returns the result. If you would not do so, you are to walk out of the map at all, resulting in attempt to access `n-th` element within `world[-12][N]`, which is `nil[N]`, which leads to an error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a recursive call. When you calculated an element of the array , the function calls itself with 8 elements nearby, and if the element is not "land", it finishes the calculating.

If you remove the line "return", it will execute forever until stackoverflow or out of bound of array...